# Determine the horizontal tangent to the graph of the trigonometric function $f(x) = 2x + \sqrt{3}\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given y = 2x + √3 cosx, find all horizontal tangents and write a general solution for x.

To find horizontal tangents, we derive and equal to 0:

y' = 2 - √3 sinx ; y'=0

2 - √3 sinx = 0

sinx= 2/√3

x = arcsin(2/√3)

However, arcsin(2/√3) is not a real number.

Upon graphing, I found the horizontal tangents to be x = π/2 + πn where n is an integer.

But I don't know how to find the x values without graphing.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think the function has real horizontal tangent lines? Unless you meant $f(x)=x \sqrt{3}+ 2 \cos(x)$ it does have real horizontal tangents.

Proceeding with the original function by taking the first derivative:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\ (2x+\sqrt{3}\ \cos(x)) = 2 - \sqrt{3}\ \sin(x)$$
Setting it equal to zero:

$$2 - \sqrt{3} \ \sin(x) = 0$$
$$\sin(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} = \frac{2}{3} \sqrt{3} \ \approx 1.1547$$

Since the range of any sine function is $-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$, $1.15$ exceeds $1$, so in conclusion, the function $f(x) = 2x - \sqrt{3} \ \cos(x)$ does not have any real horizontal tangent lines.

Comment: You probably mistyped the function. But in your question the function does not have any real tangent lines.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't mistype the function, but I was confused, thinking the horizontal tangent lines were to be found on the derivative and not the original function.

Comment: But how did you get x to be pi/2?

Comment: If you graph f'(x) = 2 - √3 cos(x) you can see tangent lines, aka the periodicity of the graph, every π/2 (max & mins). See Átila's second graph below, or plug into desmos to see the points (couldn't attach a screenshot here). 

My original question though was how can we find the π/2 value without graphing!

Comment: Oh, that is the part you misunderstood. We know $f'(x) = 2 - \sqrt{3} sinx$ has to be zero, right? Well, that means that f'(x) has to intersect the x axis. That is the definition for a function to be equal to zero. In the second picture, you can see f'(x) doesnt actually crossed the x axis!

Comment: You can always check if your solution is correct. Try plugging in $x = \frac{\pi}2$ to $f'(x)$. You can see that $2 - \sqrt{3} ≠ 0$, you $x = \frac{\pi}2$ is not a solution

Comment: Yes, understood! Thanks for elaborating. And by the way, I thought you'd like to know that my teacher later told me that the problem was 'wrong', meaning she didn't intend to give a problem that didn't have any real solutions. Hence the confusing premise!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the graph of the proposed function $f(x) = 2x + \sqrt{3}\cos(x)$
[image]

And here is the graph of its derivative $f'(x) = 2 - \sqrt{3}\sin(x)$

[image]

As it can be seen, $f'(x) > 0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (that is because $2 > \sqrt{3}$ and $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$).

Consequently, there is no horizontal tangent line due to the [Fermat's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points))